# I removed the original MBR on a Acer notebook, how to access the recovery partition?

Tags: laptop, acer-aspire

I have an acer notebook. I installed my own copy of windows 7 (...) and I kept the recovery partition. But now, how do I access it? If I press F12 a boot menu comes out, but it doesn't propose the recovery partition, just standard win7 startup options.

How do I boot into recovery now?

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd> keys during boot-up to access the recovery partition. For more details, try [this search](https://www.google.com/search?client=gmail&rls=gm&q=acer%20notebook%20boot%20into%20recovery%20partition&safe=active)